# How to extract the first element of a 3d array in Excel?

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, excel-formula

Say I have this function **f**, which gives me a 3d array output. I just want the very first element in that array. Is there a way that I can extract the element to a cell? For example,

```
res = f(A5,...)
```

And I only want

```
res(0,0,0)
```

in cell **U5**.

Comment: Show your input then desired output?

Comment: what is the ... is the  -->  f(A5,...)  ?

Comment: `excel-formula` has been tagged, though I believe this requires some clarification, since that would suggest no VBA, though that would not appear to be the case?